# Dois Android ProgressDialog um após o outro

Tags: java, android

Como faço para exibir dois progress Dialog, quando um terminar, abrir o outro?

No meu caso o usuário clica num botão, ai vários arquivos de uma pasta são movidas e renomeados para outra pasta, ele primeiro envia tudo, depois renomeia. Então eu teria que ter 2 progress dialogs, um para quando estiver enviando, e o outro para quando estiver renomeando. Mas somente aparecer quando o outro sumir...

Eu preciso de progress dialog para renomear pois são mais de 200 arquivos.

Pesquisei e parece que não é possível. Alguma ideia?

Comment: O ideal não seria um progress bar mostrando as etapas que ele executa?

Comment: Acho bem legal a ideia do @Reiksiel, até pensando em UX mesmo. Acho que depois do primeiro diálogo o usuário não espera outro hehe. Tente usar um `DialogFragment`,  nele você pode customizar a `View` e colocar um `TextView` com as etapas.

Comment: não havia pensado nisso... Mas não tem como alterar o titulo e mensagem do Dialog dentro da thread? Eu precisaria mudar eles também, tentei mas simplesmente não altera...

Comment: @Wakim agora ficou bom, consegui fazer... Faz uma resposta mostrando um exemplo de como customizar a view nessa parte, que eu escolho a resposta

Comment: @felipe.rce, já tem uma resposta com essa idéia. Se não foi como você implementou, você poder escrever a resposta e aceitar. Ficando como informação para os próximos que vierem ter essa dúvida.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Faz assim:**

```
public static class OperationFiles extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer,Void>
    {
    public enum Operation
    {
      Move,
      Rename
    }

    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    private Context context;
    private OnPostExecuteListener onPostExecuteListener;
    private List<File> filesList;
    private String destino;
    private Operation operation;


    public OnPostExecuteListener getOnPostExecuteListener() {
        return onPostExecuteListener;
    }

    public void setOnPostExecuteListener(OnPostExecuteListener onPostExecuteListener) {
        this.onPostExecuteListener = onPostExecuteListener;
    }

    //aqui você pode receber a lista de arquivos e o novo local
    public OperationFiles(Context context,List<File> filesList, String destino, Operation operation)
    {
        this.context = context;
        this.progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
        this.filesList = filesList;
        this.destino = destino;
        this.operation = operation;
    }


    @Override
    public void onPreExecute()
    {
        if(operation == Operation.Move)
            this.progressDialog.setMessage("Movendo os arquivos...");
        else
            this.progressDialog.setMessage("Renomeando os arquivos...");

        this.progressDialog.setMax(filesList.size());
        this.progressDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids)
    {

        for(int i = 0; i < filesList.size(); i++)
        {
            //faz a operação para defina no construtor aqui
            if(operation == Operation.Move)
            {

            }
            else
            {

            }

            //itera no progresso
            publishProgress(i);
        }

        return null;
    }


    @Override
    public void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress)
    {
        this.progressDialog.setProgress(progress[0]);
    }


    @Override
    public void onPostExecute(Void result)
    {
        //dismiss do diálogo
        this.progressDialog.dismiss();

        //chama o callback informando o término do processo
        if(getOnPostExecuteListener() != null)
            getOnPostExecuteListener().onPostExecute();
    }

    //Irá fazer um callback para quando o processo terminar
    public interface OnPostExecuteListener{
        public void onPostExecute();
    }
}
```

Considere que esse é um exemplo e você pode alterar de acordo com seu problema.
Dessa forma que fiz, assim que uma operação é terminada, ele chama a outra, fazendo dois diálogos diferentes serem executados.

**O uso ficaria assim:**

```
 //Faz a operacao de mover os arquivos
        OperationFiles operationFiles = new OperationFiles(this, new ArrayList<File>(), "/sdcard...", OperationFiles.Operation.Move );

    //informa o callback
    operationFiles.setOnPostExecuteListener(new OperationFiles.OnPostExecuteListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onPostExecute()
        {
            ///aqui a operacao de renomear
            OperationFiles operationFilesRename = new OperationFiles(Main.this, new ArrayList<File>(), "/sdcard...", OperationFiles.Operation.Rename);
            operationFilesRename.execute();
        }
    });

    operationFiles.execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

Da forma que você colocou ficou bem genérico, mas você pode colocar ao final da 1 thread ( enviando arquivos) chamar o dismiss() da 1 ProgressDialog, e logo em seguida chamar a 2 thread (renomear arquivos) essa thread vai chamar a 2 ProgressDialog e no final chamar o dismiss() da mesma.